# not finding ResolutionPolicy in cocos2d-x 3.0 for ios platform

Tags: cocos2d-x

I am not finding ResolutionPolicy inside CCEgleViewProtocol.
Can any one please help me in getting ResolutionPolicy, and setting images for mutiresolution.
I am using cocos2d-x 3.0 beta version.

Comment: can you show some code, please.

Answer (score 0):

Cocos2d-x 3.0 comes with the concepts of design resolution size (with associated resolution policy) and content scale factor that you can use as follow:

1) First you have to retrieve your glview

```
auto director = Director::getInstance();
auto glview = director->getOpenGLView();
if(!glview) {
    glview = GLView::create("My game");
    director->setOpenGLView(glview);
}
```

2) then you can access to real screen size

```
Size screenSize = glview->getFrameSize();
```

3) then you have to set your design size (it depends on your target devices and your assets resolution)

```
//set design size for iPad retina
Size designSize = Size(2048, 1536);

glview->setDesignResolutionSize (
     designSize.width,
     designSize.height,
     ResolutionPolicy::SHOW_ALL <-- HERE YOU CAN SET RESOLUTION POLICY
);
```

4) Then you have to set your assets paths (landscape configuration is supposed here)

```
FileUtils::getInstance()->setSearchPaths({"assets"});

if (screenSize.height > 768) {
    CCLOG("ipadhd chosed");
    FileUtils::getInstance()->setSearchResolutionsOrder({"big"});
} else if (screenSize.height > 320) {
    CCLOG("ipad or iphonehd chosed");
    FileUtils::getInstance()->setSearchResolutionsOrder({"medium"});
} else {
    CCLOG("iphone chosed");
    FileUtils::getInstance()->setSearchResolutionsOrder({"small"});
}
```

This configuration presumes that your have put your assets in a 'assets' subfolder of 'Resources' folder. Then you have divided 'assets' into three subfolders called 'big', 'medium' and 'small'

5) Finally you have to set your content scale factor

```
director->setContentScaleFactor(screenSize.height/designSize.height);
```